# CSV data display in column format?

Tags: css, csv

I have a simple csv line taked from a txt file. This line is showed by default like a simple row, like this:

> 125922 1   1   1   4.613   4.985   16.164  27.618  4.990   16.169

And i need show this on columns, like this:

> 125922 
> 1 
> 1 
> 1 
> 4.613 
> 4.985 
> 16.164 
> 27.618 
> 4.990 
> 16.169

Someone has an idea?

My idea was using css, or a simple php code o javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) would probably do the trick since you're just switching out tabs for new lines:

```
echo str_replace("\t", "\n", "125922 1 1 1 4.613 4.985 16.164 27.618 4.990 16.169");
```

If it is being output to a web browsers use:

```
echo str_replace("\t", "<br>", "125922 1 1 1 4.613 4.985 16.164 27.618 4.990 16.169");
```